# Print a form in Symfony 3 with collectionType

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I work with Symfony 3 and I have a problem with printing a form. It contains a collectionType

When I make `form_start(form)` all the fields are printed.

But I want to personnalize the display of the collectionType.

Code:

```
{% for tab in form.tabs %}
          {{ form_row(tab.rep) }}
          {{ form_row(tab.charge) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But no fields are printed.

My form is ok:

```
FormView {#591 ▼
  +vars: array:27 [▶]
  +parent: FormView {#584 ▼
    +vars: array:24 [▶]
    +parent: null
    +children: array:4 [▼
      "tabs" => FormView {#591}
      "blabla" => FormView {#587 ▶}
      "save" => FormView {#581 ▶}
      "_token" => FormView {#567 ▶}
    ]
    -rendered: false
  }
  +children: []
  -rendered: true
}
```

Why is it ok with form_start but not with the loop for?

Answer (score 0):

If form.tabs is not populate, Symfony doesn't know how many tabs form show. You have to use Javascript to allow Client to add dynamicaly Tabs Form https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Yes, I have a JS which add tabs form.

Comment: Thanks Smaîne, i have add my JS. It's work with form_start()

Answer (score 0):

I want put my two input inline, by default there are on row each

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
/****OCR*******/
// On récupère la balise <div> en question qui contient l'attribut « data-prototype » qui nous intéresse.
    var $container = $('div#alex_platformbundle_seance_exercice_serie_series');


    // On définit un compteur unique pour nommer les champs qu'on va ajouter dynamiquement

    var index = $container.find(':input').length;


    // On ajoute un nouveau champ à chaque clic sur le lien d'ajout.

    $('#add_category').click(function(e) {
        //$('#alex_platformbundle_exercice_series_0_exercice').val("1");

        //$('#alex_platformbundle_seance_exercice_serie_series_0_exercice').val(2);
      addCategory($container);
      //i=index-1;
      test = "#alex_platformbundle_seance_exercice_serie_series_"+index+"_exercice";
        $(test).val(idEx);



      e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL

      return false;

    });


    // On ajoute un premier champ automatiquement s'il n'en existe pas déjà un (cas d'une nouvelle annonce par exemple).

    if (index == 0) {

      addCategory($container);

    } else {

      // S'il existe déjà des catégories, on ajoute un lien de suppression pour chacune d'entre elles

      $container.children('div').each(function() {

        addDeleteLink($(this));

      });

    }


    // La fonction qui ajoute un formulaire CategoryType

    function addCategory($container) {

      // Dans le contenu de l'attribut « data-prototype », on remplace :

      // - le texte "__name__label__" qu'il contient par le label du champ

      // - le texte "__name__" qu'il contient par le numéro du champ

      var template = $container.attr('data-prototype')

        .replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Serie n°' + (index+1) +" : "+ nameEx )

        .replace(/__name__/g,        index)

      ;


      // On crée un objet jquery qui contient ce template

      var $prototype = $(template);


      // On ajoute au prototype un lien pour pouvoir supprimer la catégorie

      addDeleteLink($prototype);


      // On ajoute le prototype modifié à la fin de la balise <div>

      $container.append($prototype);

     test = "#alex_platformbundle_seance_exercice_serie_series_"+index+"_exercice";
    $(test).val(idEx);
      // Enfin, on incrémente le compteur pour que le prochain ajout se fasse avec un autre numéro

      index++;

    }


    // La fonction qui ajoute un lien de suppression d'une catégorie

    function addDeleteLink($prototype) {

      // Création du lien

      var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');


      // Ajout du lien

      $prototype.append($deleteLink);


      // Ajout du listener sur le clic du lien pour effectivement supprimer la catégorie

      $deleteLink.click(function(e) {

        $prototype.remove();


        e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL

        return false;

      });

    }

/**************/

  });
</script>
```